# Troubleshooting a problem: Roblox account hacked

Tags: roblox

Recently my roblox account is hacked and password was changed. In addition, "something went wrong" popped up when I tried to change my password. My Gmail has a notification mentioning my account was hacked. What should I do to recover my account?

Comment: "Something went wrong" means the reset password link probably expired; try sending another one.

Comment: I couldn't even send the link to my Gmail, that's the problem

Comment: That means they've changed the recovery email. You'll need to contact roblox support at `https://www.roblox.com/support` or `info@roblox.com` @00xxqhxx00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact roblox [here](https://www.roblox.com/support) and tell them about your problem. The hacker probably changed the email linked to the account.